# How to get the lifetime from an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of strings that characterize the period of life.
How to find the life expectancy of everyone?

```js
let array = ["1910-1997", "1745-1790", "1660-1740"];

function getLifespan(years) {}

getLifespan(array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let array = ["1910-1997", "1745-1790", "1660-1740"];

function getLifespan(years) {
  return years.map(year => {
    let [start, end] = year.split('-')
    return end - start;
  })
}

const result = getLifespan(array);


console.log(result)
```